# Polyline drawing dot not a line

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am wanting to be able to draw a poly line from an array of coordinates.
How ever when using the code below it will only draw a dot rather then a line to each lat/lng in the array.
How can I make it so it will draw a line to from each lat/lng to form a line?
Code:

```
var poly = new Array();    
for (var j = 0; j<p.Cot.length; j++) {
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(p.Cot[0],p.Cot[1])
    poly.push(pos);
}

        var Path = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: poly,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#ff004c',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 5
  });
  Path.setMap(Map);
```

Array:
(The first object is the lat, the second is the lng, 3rd is the heading and the 4th is the altitude).

> Cot":[33.091415,-112.142067,null,null,33.09549,-112.142998,25.0,1500.0,33.095802,-112.143333,320.0,2000.0,33.097103,-112.145912,320.0,2000.0,33.097431,-112.147766,290.0,2000.0,33.097523,-112.149841,275.0,2000.0,33.097595,-112.152176,275.0,2000.0,33.097618,-112.152527,270.0,2000.0,33.097801,-112.158356,270.0,2000.0]},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "points" are sets of 4 numbers in the array.  Increment through the array by 4, `index+0` is the latitude, `index+1` is the longitude.

```
var poly = [];
for (var j = 0; j < p.Cot.length; j+=4) {
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(p.Cot[j], p.Cot[j+1])
  poly.push(pos);
}

var Path = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: poly,
  geodesic: true,
  strokeColor: '#ff004c',
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 5
});
Path.setMap(Map);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bxjy0k1r/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var Map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.091415, -112.142067),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var poly = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < p.Cot.length; j += 4) {
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(p.Cot[j], p.Cot[j + 1])
    poly.push(pos);
  }

  var Path = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: poly,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#ff004c',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 5
  });
  Path.setMap(Map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
var p = {
  Cot: [33.091415, -112.142067, null, null, 33.09549, -112.142998, 25.0, 1500.0, 33.095802, -112.143333, 320.0, 2000.0, 33.097103, -112.145912, 320.0, 2000.0, 33.097431, -112.147766, 290.0, 2000.0, 33.097523, -112.149841, 275.0, 2000.0, 33.097595, -112.152176, 275.0, 2000.0, 33.097618, -112.152527, 270.0, 2000.0, 33.097801, -112.158356, 270.0, 2000.0]
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```